# Angular: NPM installation stalls out when creating project

Tags: angular

I just tried to create a new project and its for some reason getting hung up on installing the node packages.  I had this same problem when I installed v16 of Angular but I wound up fixing it by installing the latest version of Typescript.

As of right now I have:

Node 18.16.0

NPM 7.21.0

Angular 16.1.3

Typescript 5.1.6

Windows 10 64bit

I tried running `ng new my-app --standalone` and it got hung up for over 20 minutes.  I tried it again without the standalone flag and the same thing happened.  I ran `npm cache clean --force` and tried again.  I tried generating the app with the `--skip-install` flag to run `npm install` separately and it didn't do anything but stay stuck on `sill idealtree builddeps`.  I came across a solution that said to delete the `package-lock.json` file and try running `npm install` however there was no `package-lock.json` file in the app.  I've come across several articles on this issue and they all provide the same handful of solutions that don't seem to resolve the problem.  Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to this issue https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3257.

It is about version of npm v7 and v8
So upgrade npm to higher version (recommend 9.5.1),

I try this command successfully

```
ng new my-app --standalone
```

with this environment:

- Angular CLI: 16.2.0
- Node: 18.16.0
- Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
- OS: win32 x64

Comment: Ok that solved the problem.  However in an app I built almost a month ago I'm trying to install angular elements and it's stalling the same exact way.  Is there anything I should update in that project to get it to work?  I updated both node and npm.

Comment: Do you mean to update some libraries and elements for an existed project?
if yes, it should be done with suggestion of angular guild https://update.angular.io/