# Angular Elements won't install in my project

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I'm trying to add angular elements to my project and the installation gets stuck.  When I built this project I had node 18.6.0 and npm 7.21.0  A couple days ago I ran into this same problem trying to start a new angular app and posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872164/angular-npm-installation-stalls-out-when-creating-project/76872675#76872675) where I was told it was a bug with npm v7 and that I should update it.  I updated to node 18.17.1 and to npm 9.8.1 and I was able to create the new app.  When I try adding `@angular/elements` to an app I created with the older versions by running `npm install @angular/elements` I run into this problem again.  I tried adding `"@angular/elements": "^16.2.0"` to my `package.json` file and running `npm install` and it gets stuck until it eventually times out.  Are there any modificiations I need to make in my `package.json` or `package-lock.json` files to get things working again?  I don't know what else to try.